# OSError when tried to load librosa (import soundfile error)

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder, librosa, soundfile

When I ran `import librosa`, I got the following error message:

`OSError: cannot load library 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\sndfile.dll': error 0x7e`

and

`OSError: cannot load library 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_soundfile_data\libsndfile64bit.dll': error 0x7e`.

I installed librosa package with `conda install -c conda-forge librosa`, `pysound` with `conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile`, and `soundfile` with `pip install SoundFile`.

But this didn't solve the problem.
Does anyone got a similar error or know how to fix this?

Update: I created a new environment on anaconda and installed `librosa`. This fixed the loading issue, but I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this issue in my base environment.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem as a brute force approach but uninstalling and then installing the same module worked for me

Comment: this didnt work for me, the error still pops up after uninstall & reinstall